# How to Invoke the script created in Automation tab of soapui in my groovy script?

Tags: javascript, groovy, soapui

I have implemented the java script in the Automation window of SOAP UI in the Oauth Profile.

```
if (document.getElementById('login')){document.getElementById('login').value = 'xxxx@xxx.com';document.getElementById('password').value = 'xxxxx';document.loginform.submit();
```

}

Now, I am using the Testrunner batch file to run my testcases/test steps from Groovy script.

how can i invoke the above code in my groovy script for one of my Test Step/Case to generate User Token ?

Comment: Hi all - Any suggestions would be of help.